# Sum of digits (INC. Negative numbers)

Tags: java

How can I make the following allow negative numbers and treats them as positives.  Ex. -91 = 10
It currently works for taking int n and adding all digits, but just for positives.  Thanks!

```
public static int sumOfDigits(int n) {
  int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return sum;
 }
```

Comment: n = Math.abs(n). There is no recursion at all here. Why the title?

Comment: @JBNizet `n = Math.abs(n)` fails for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: add `n = Math.abs(n)` as the first line of the function. This solution works for all numbers, except [Integer.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE).

Always correct solution: replace loop condition by `n != 0` and return `Math.abs(sum)` as the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sumOfDigits(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    else return (n % 10) + sumOfDigits(n / 10);
}
```

Comment: Could do with a bit of commenting seeing as OP is using a non recursive method

Comment: In the first version of this post the author asked for a recursive way to calculate his function. Therefore I've added a recursive version.

Comment: I've tried to match his method. Now it won't return 0 for negative numbers anymore.